# INDIRECT function in LibreOffice not as in OpenOffice

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have a speadsheet that has become rather unstable in OpenOffice, and I'm hoping that LibreOffice might be more reliable (I don't really want to pay for MS Excel).

I have a sheet which has a column of sheet names (Col A) and data transferred from those sheets in other columns.  This has been working in OpenOffice, but not in LibreOffice.

For example, I need cell B3 on this page to show the contents of cell L14 on the page which has the same name as the contents of cell A3.  The coding I am using on OpenOffice that achieves this perfectly well is `=INDIRECT($A3&"!$L$14")`.  (I want B4 to show the L14 value of the sheet named in A4 and so on.)

Opening the same file in LibreOffice doesn't recognise this coding, and my page is full of #REF! warnings shouting at me.  The rest of the data has transferred fine.

I have tried many permutations of changing single and double quotes, ampersands, commas and full stops, but no joy yet.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The LibreOffice Calc help has this caveat, which seems revelant: "If you open a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet that uses indirect addresses calculated from string functions, the sheet addresses will not be translated automatically. For example, the Microsoft Excel address in INDIRECT("filename!sheetname"&B1) is not converted into the Calc address in INDIRECT("filename.sheetname"&B1)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `LibreOffice Calc` uses `.` (dot) instead of `!` (as `Excel` does)
to separate the sheet name in a reference, 
so you can just replace `!` with `.` in formulas.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit**

You can also try to open `LibreOffice Calc` 
and convert `Excel` documents to `.ods` format with
`File > Wizards > Document converter`.

Comment: That's brilliant: a really quick solution after a lot of frustrating fumbling around.

Comment: LO Calc defaults to slightly different formula syntax, but you can change it to match Excel.  In `Tools | Options | LibreOffice Calc | Formulas | Formula Options | Formula Syntax` there's a drop-down menu.  Select Excel A1.

Comment: @fixer1234: That's good to know, thanks. 
This would be a better option.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of LibreOffice Calc set a new per-document option: "Reference syntax for string references" that makes the behavior of INDIRECT more interoperable. This is set as we load any XLS or XLSX document, and preserved as an option in ODF files too - so, this should be a complete non-issue with a modern LibreOffice. Thanks to Kohei Yoshida (at Collabora) and Bubli Behrens (at CIB).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make a formula compatible with both syntax versions and to fix the #REF! errors:

### Solution

Instead of

`=INDIRECT("SheetName!A1")`

or

`=INDIRECT("SheetName.A1")`

you can use IFERROR() to pass both syntaxes:

`=IFERROR(INDIRECT("SheetName!A1");INDIRECT("SheetName.A1"))`

### Explanation

As stated correctly in other answers, different office tools use a different syntax to reference a cell in another sheet. OpenOffice.org and Microsoft Office use an exclamation mark `!` as a separator, but LibreOffice uses a dot `.` instead.

By using one of the syntaxes, your file will open and evaluate just fine in the corresponding office solution, but will generate a #REF! error in others.

Using [IFERROR()](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060104.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id31470811) with both syntaxes solves this incompatibility issue. If you open the sheet with MS Excel, the first INDIRECT() statement (using the exclamation mark `!` syntax) will be evaluated. If it is a valid reference containing a valid value, this value will be returned as a result. But if you open the sheet with LibreOffice, the first INDIRECT() statement will return a #REF error, therefore the IFERROR() function will try to evaluate the second INDIRECT() statement (using the dot `.` syntax).

In your case, the formula for cell B3 would be:

`=IFERROR(INDIRECT($A3&"!$L$14");INDIRECT($A3&".$L$14"))`